# (Another) invalid audit

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5213109). It appears to me that there is a description of the problem and sufficient code, unlike the reason shown for closure claims.

Since [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091723/why-webrenderer-swing-editon-doesnt-load-audio-and-video-local-files) has been deleted by a mod, I can't see the edit history.

Question 1: Was the above question edited after it was closed? And, if yes,
Question 2: Shouldn't questions that were edited after closure be ineligible to be an audit?

Comment: *sigh* Stupid people abusing VLQ flags on questions.

Comment: That question was not edited after it was closed, or at all, for that matter.

Comment: @Servy Do you consider the reason for closure valid?

Comment: @Mooseman I don't know enough about the subject matter to say conclusively, but it at least seems plausible to me that the question doesn't contain enough information to be answerable (which is why it's closed) as it seems like it might be an environmental/data issue, rather than a code issue.